# Infinite sum, not arithemtic nor geometric progression.

Tags: analysis

How could you compute this:

$$\sum_{n}^\infty\frac{1}{\left( 2n+1\right)^4}$$

I know the solution is $\pi^4/96$, according to Maple, but I have no idea how to do this or how to start.

Comment: Can you first show what $\sum \frac{1}{n^4}$ is?

Comment: What mathematics do you know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At heart, this is a simple consequence of the result:

$$\frac{\pi^4}{90}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}$$

Then your value is:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^4} &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)^4} \\&= \left(1-\frac{1}{16}\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}
\end{align}
$$

You might also see the answers at: [Nice proofs of $\zeta(4) = \pi^4/90$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28329/nice-proofs-of-zeta4-pi4-90) for why the first statement is true.