# Extending the Basel problem for 1/n^4

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

Is there any way to prove that:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} = \frac{\pi^4}{90} $$

Using Euler's original proof of equating coefficients?

Comment: I had a look there but no one uses the same proof that Euler did which what i'm interested in

Comment: The answer with score 25. That is the closest to Euler's method.

Comment: Yes it's very close and a nice proof but I' trying to find how Euler did it using only his original proof.

Comment: See [1st comment  there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989923/evaluation-of-int-infty-0-fracx3ex-1dx/1990027#comment4087946_1990027) for a derivation from $\frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-n)^2}$

Comment: The answer with score 14 is also the method that Euler used for Basel problem!

Comment: Someone knows if Euler could prove that $\pi \cot(z) = \lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=-N}^N\frac{1}{z-n}$ without making some complicated digressions about $\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{ x}$ Weierstrass product ? I think he had some problems because he wasn't thinking to meromorphic functions of $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: @user1952009 Sh... believe in the great Euler XD.  And theres that other squeeze theorem proof Euler gave too.

Comment: @SimpleArt hmm ?

Comment: @user1952009 Just reminding that there is a second proof that uses the squeeze theorem instead.

Comment: @user1952009 [Rigorous proof concerning the Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#A_rigorous_elementary_proof)

Comment: @SimpleArt I don't see how it is related to what I wrote, which is not about proving $\zeta(2) = \pi^2/6$, but $k! 2 (2^{2k}-1)\zeta(2k) = f^{(k)}(1/2)$ from $f(z) = \frac{\pi^2}{\sin(\pi z)^2} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-n)^2}$. So I ask if Euler could prove $\frac{\pi^2}{\sin(\pi z)^2} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-n)^2}$ rigorously, and without making some complicated digressions about (his) product formula for $\sin(x), x \in \mathbb{R}$