# Use $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$ to compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Is it possible to use the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$ to compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^4}$?

Comment: Wait, I think I'm reading this wrong, but if $k$ is fixed, then it is either going to be $\frac{\pi^4}{90}$ or the negative of that. Do you mean $-1^n$?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Updated

Comment: You mean $(-1)^n$, not $-1^n$, right? The parentheses make a difference. (and $(-1)^n$, not $-1^k$, in the title)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Here I'll assume that $-1^k$ here ought to be $(-1)^k$.) Hint:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^4} = -\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} + 2 \sum_{n > 1 \text{ even}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} = - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} + 2 \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 n)^4}.$$

> This is $$- \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} + \frac{1}{8} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} = - \frac{7}{8} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}.$$

Comment: $n=0???\phantom{      }$

Comment: Thanks, fixed it in the edit.

Comment: Nice answer otherwise. +1

Comment: Cheers, thanks for helping improve it.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Note

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^4}=2\left(\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{4^4}+\dots+\right)=\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{1}{1^4}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\dots\right)=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let 
$$E=\sum_{n=1, n=even}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}$$
$$O=\sum_{n=1, n=odd}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}$$

You are given that $E+O=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$ and want to find $E-O$.
To do this note that
$$E=\sum_{n=1, n=even}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)^4}=\frac{1}{16}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^4}=\frac{1}{16}\frac{\pi^4}{90}$$