# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n/(n^4)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$$ find $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^4}$$
The answer should be $\frac{-7\pi^4}{720}$.

Comment: This has been asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169861/use-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n4-frac-pi490-to-compute-sum-n-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^4} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^4}- \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^4}$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^4} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^4}$$