# How come pi is in this question?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

I was doing my homework assignment and I did this question correctly. However, I'm interested in knowing the reason behind the logic that how $1/1^4 + 1/2^4 + 1/3^4$ .... to infinity evaluates to $pi^4/90$

Also, I know that whenever there is pi, somehow everything is related to circle. How is this question related to circle?

Here's a screenshot of my question if that helps! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This series can be derived by using Eulers Product representation of the sine function. And the Taylor series of the sine function. In general $$1+\frac{1}{2^{2n}}+\frac{1}{3^{2n}}+\frac{1}{4^{2n}}+\cdots = A\cdot\pi^{2n}$$ Where $A$ is a rational number, which is related to the Bernoulli numbers. Here is a video series (https://goo.gl/0oENyJ).

Comment: The formula here is one of several [special values of the Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function), $\zeta(4) = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$.  The Riemann zeta function at $2n$ is $(2\pi)^{2n}$ times a rational number connected with the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).

Comment: Same question as:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28329/nice-proofs-of-zeta4-pi4-90