# Calculate sequence using the Fourier sequence?

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

I've been learning Fourier sequence for a while and now I'm stuck. I have a function $$f(x)=x^2,\quad x\in[-\pi, \pi ]$$ and once evaluating this to Fourier we get:
$$f(x)=\frac{\pi^2}{3} + 4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{-n}}{n^2}\,\cos{(nx)}$$

Now it says: with the aid of the Fourier sequence (above) calculate the following sequence: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}$$

How do I tackle such problem, I've goggled everything but haven't found anything similar.
 Any help on this?

Comment: Its just https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem

Comment: So basically I use the information from the calculated series of x^2 and plug it into Parsevals formula?

Comment: thats exactly right.

Comment: Tnx, I l give it a try right away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) we get

$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(x^2)^2\,dx =2\pi\cdot\frac{\pi^4}{9}+16\pi \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^4}\tag{1} $$
but the LHS of $(1)$ equals $\frac{2\pi^5}{5}$, hence by rearranging we get:
$$ \zeta(4)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^4}=\frac{1}{16\pi}\left(\frac{2\pi^5}{5}-\frac{2\pi^5}{9}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{\pi^4}{90}}.\tag{2}$$
Have also a look at [this historical thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28329/nice-proofs-of-zeta4-pi4-90).

Comment: Thank you Sir, the answer that you got is listed within my answers! Can you suggest any other series apart from 1/n^4 to practice, I see that this is one is very popular.

Comment: @wesewx, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28329/nice-proofs-of-zeta4-pi4-90?noredirect=1&lq=1