# Understanding $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, fourier-analysis, proof-explanation

> In the answer, of this question [Nice proofs of $\zeta(4) = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28329/nice-proofs-of-zeta4-frac-pi490), given by Christian Blatter,
>
> - Why $|c_{\pm k}|^2={1\over4}a_k^2={4\over k^4}$ $\ (k\geq1)$ ?
>
> According to my calculations $|c_{\pm k}|^2=\vert1/2\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi t^2e^{-i(\pm k)x}dx\vert^2=\vert t^2\sin(\pi(\pm k))/\pi(\pm k)\vert^2=0$
>
> - And how did he get $\frac{\pi^4}{90}?$

Consider the function $f(t):=t^2\ \ (-\pi\leq t\leq \pi)$, extended to all of ${\mathbb R}$ periodically with period $2\pi$. Developping $f$ into a  Fourier series we get
$$t^2 ={\pi^2\over3}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty {4(-1)^k\over k^2}\cos(kt)\qquad(-\pi\leq t\leq \pi).$$
If we put $t:=\pi$ here we easily find $\zeta(2)={\pi^2\over6}$. For $\zeta(4)$ we use Parseval's formula
$$\|f\|^2=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |c_k|^2\ .$$ Here
$$\|f\|^2={1\over2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi t^4\>dt={\pi^4\over5}$$
and the $c_k$ are the complex Fourier coefficients of $f$. Therefore $c_0={\pi^2\over3}$ and $|c_{\pm k}|^2={1\over4}a_k^2={4\over k^4}$ $\ (k\geq1)$. Putting it all together gives $\zeta(4)={\pi^4\over 90}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the inner product,
$\langle a , b \rangle = {1 \over 2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \overline{a(t)} b(t) dt $,
the complex Fourier series for $f$ is given by $\hat{f_k} = {1 \over 2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-ikt} f(t) dt $.

The function is reconstituted (in a $L^2$ sense) by $f(t) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\hat{f_k} e^{ikt}$.

Parseval's theorem gives
$\|f\|^2_2 = { 1\over 2 \pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(t)|^2 dt = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}|\hat{f_k}|^2$.

In this case, $f(t) = t^2$, hence $\|f\|^2_2 = {\pi^4 \over 5}$,
and the complex Fourier series given by $\hat{f_0} = {\pi ^2 \over 3}$ and for $k \neq 0$, we have $\hat{f_k}={1 \over 2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi t^2 \cos (kt) dt = (-1)^k {2 \over k^2}$.

Then ${\pi^4 \over 5} = \sum_{k <0} {4 \over k^4} + {\pi^4 \over 9} + \sum_{k >0} {4 \over k^4} = {\pi^4 \over 9} + 2 \sum_{k >0} {4 \over k^4}$,
which simplifies to the desired result.

Comment: I see :) ${}{}$

Comment: How was $\frac{\pi^4}{90}$ calculated? I suppose I have to mix $c_0$ and $c_k$ in the series, but how do it? If you notice the series it's not usual, I mean it starts in $-\infty$.

Comment: Parseval's theorem gives an equivalence between $\|f\|^2$ and the summation of coefficients squared. The integral is straightforward to compute. That was the point of Christian's answer.

Comment: Yes I know, but how should I substitute $\frac{4}{k^4}$ in $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |c_k|^2\ .$? how will I include the $c_0$?

Comment: Also I think this is not the correct summation $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |c_k|^2$ should be $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |c_k|^2\ .$

Comment: If you are using $e_n(t) = e^{int}$ as a basis (which I did above) then the summation is over the integers. If you use $t \mapsto \cos (nt)$, $t \mapsto \sin(nt)$ then the $c_k$ needs an extra factor and the summation is over the non negative integers.

Comment: I could quite easily have a scaling bug above, will check later.

Comment: :( ok, if could elaborate on the substitutions to get $\frac{\pi^4}{90}$ that would be great

Comment: It is an application of Parseval's theorem, not a substitution as such.

Comment: I added an elaboration.

Comment: ah didn't know you were going to help 8 hours later.. I asked a new question about it

Comment: @Alt. On the Stack Exchange sites it is frowned upon to add duplicate questions...

Comment: You should have told me: I am going to help you 8 hours/10 hours/ .../ later. How would I know you were going to do it? I though you wouldn't

Comment: I sincerely hope you are joking. This is not a paid site. You need to reset your expectations.

Comment: I though you wouldn't and I _really_ needed the answer.

Comment: Oh, I see, in that case I could have canceled my Mother's Day plans in order to suit your need to have it right now.

Comment: No, please don't take this the wrong way. I forgot about Mother's day in your country. Btw you have answered questions (mine) before and you usually reply fast, this time was different.